# Select a record which has the highest value in a column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a column called 'frequency' in my database. I want to select the records of a particular category in which frequency is more. Like there will be 5 records of same category but each may have different frequency. Out of all these 5 records, I want the record whose value in frequency is more.

Say,

record 1 frequency value = 10 
record 2 frequency value = 20 
record 3 frequency value = 30 
record 4 frequency value = 10 
record 5 frequency value = 50 
I want record 5 as my output.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try doing this

```
Record.where(category: 'animal').maximum("value")
```

or you could try this

```
Record.where(category: 'animal').order("value DESC").first
```

or

```
# 1
Record.where(category: :animal).order(value: :desc).first

# 2
Record.where(category: :animal).order(:value).last
```

Comment: works! thanks. Eventually figured it out just now, for anyone who has the same problem, can actually visit this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#calculations

Comment: No prob glad I could help

Answer (score 3):

```
YourModelName.order("frequency DESC").first
```